# Flink run: ClassNotFound Exception when casting with asInstanceOf

Tags: java, scala, apache-flink, classnotfoundexception

I'm running a fat jar from the command line (standalone cluster) and it seems that all user code is visible at runtime (evident by the logs. see workflow.provider package) except for when casting with asInstanceOf where it throws a ClassNotFoundException. Tried setting the classpath (-C) whithout much luck. Any thoughts? It works fine from IDE I'm using flink 1.9 scala 2.12

```
private def deserializeFile(fn: String): List[SDFAInterface] = {
   val oisDFA = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fn))
   val sdfa = oisDFA.readObject.asInstanceOf[List[SDFAInterface]] // SDFAProvider.scala:273
   oisDFA.close
   sdfa
}


org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error: fsm.SDFAInterface
at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:593)
at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:438)
at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:274)
at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:746)
at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.runProgram(CliFrontend.java:273)
at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:205)
at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseParameters(CliFrontend.java:1010)
at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$10(CliFrontend.java:1083)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.NoOpSecurityContext.runSecured(NoOpSecurityContext.java:30)
at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1083)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: fsm.SDFAInterface
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:720)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1925)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2099)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:465)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:423)
at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:484)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1184)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2235)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2126)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:465)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:423)
at workflow.provider.SDFAProvider.deserializeFile(SDFAProvider.scala:273)
at workflow.provider.SDFAProvider.deserialize(SDFAProvider.scala:257)
at workflow.provider.SDFAProvider.provide(SDFAProvider.scala:69)
at workflow.provider.FSMProvider.provide(FSMProvider.scala:22)
at workflow.task.engineTask.DERFTask.execute(DERFTask.scala:123)
at ui.BeepBeep$.runDistribRecognition(BeepBeep.scala:136)
at ui.WayebCLI$.runWayeb(WayebCLI.scala:612)
at ui.WayebCLI$.main(WayebCLI.scala:597)
at ui.WayebCLI.main(WayebCLI.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:576)
... 9 more
```

Comment: Check if your fat jar actually contains that class

Comment: I did and It does

Comment: I guess you have to post the script that you create your fat jar as well, maybe the `built.sbt` or the `pom.xml`.